# How to select SAME Column in SAME Table With Different Where Condition Using Yii2 QueryBuilder

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, yii2-model

Consider a Table billdetail Like this

```
__id__|__bill_id__|__weight__|__typecode__|__metal_type__|
|  1  |    2      |    5     |     S      |     GOLD     |
|  2  |    2      |    2     |     R      |     GOLD     |
|  3  |    2      |    13    |     S      |     GOLD     |
|  4  |    3      |    5     |     S      |     SILVER   |
|  5  |    3      |    2     |     S      |     SILVER   | 
|  6  |    4      |    4     |     R      |     SILVER   |
```

I try to select **weight** from this table billdetail with different condition.

```
 $bill_details = BillDetails::find()->groupby('billdetails.bill_id');                  
 $bill_details->addSelect('sum(billdetails.weight) AS gold_s_w')->andWhere(['billdetails.typecode'=>'S'])->andWhere(['billdetails.metaltype'=>'gold']);
 $bill_details->addSelect('sum(billdetails.weight) AS gold_r_w')->andWhere(['billdetails.typecode'=>'R'])->andWhere(['billdetails.metaltype'=>'gold']);
 $bill_details->addSelect('sum(billdetails.weight) AS silver_s_w')->andWhere(['billdetails.typecode'=>'S'])->andWhere(['billdetails.metaltype'=>'silver']);
 $bill_details->addSelect('sum(billdetails.weight) AS silver_s_r')->andWhere(['billdetails.typecode'=>'R'])->andWhere(['billdetails.metaltype'=>'silver']);
 $result= $bill_details->asArray()->all();
```

Results empty cause condition didn't satisfying.
its Not working It give the Rawquery-

``````````````
SELECT sum(billdetails.weight) AS gold_s_w, sum(billdetails.weight) AS gold_r_w, sum(billdetails.weight) AS silver_s_w,  
sum(billdetails.weight) AS silver_s_r
FROM `billdetails` WHERE (((((((`billdetails`.`typecode`='S') AND (`billdetails`.`metaltype`='gold')) AND (`billdetails`.`typecode`='R'))
AND (`billdetails`.`metaltype`='gold')) AND (`billdetails`.`typecode`='S')) AND (`billdetails`.`metaltype`='silver'))
AND (`billdetails`.`typecode`='R')) AND (`billdetails`.`metaltype`='silver') GROUP BY `billdetails`.`bill_id` 
`````````````
How to give Respective Where clauses for Respective Selection .
``````````````

Answer (score 0):

Your query is this (group by three columns):

```
SELECT `bill_id`, `typecode`, `metal_type`, SUM(weight) FROM `test` WHERE 1 GROUP BY `bill_id`, `typecode`, `metal_type`
```

Or in Yii2:

```
$bill_details = BillDetails::find()
->select([
    'bill_id',
    'typecode',
    'metal_type',
    'SUM(weight) as sum_weight',
])
->groupby('bill_id, typecode, metal_type')
->asArray()
->all();
```

**UPDATE:**
You can use inner select:

```
SELECT 
bill_id,
(SELECT SUM(weight) FROM test t1 WHERE t1.bill_id = t.bill_id AND t1.typecode = "S" AND t1.metal_type = "GOLD") as gold_s_w,
(SELECT SUM(weight) FROM test t1 WHERE t1.bill_id = t.bill_id AND t1.typecode = "R" AND t1.metal_type = "GOLD") as gold_r_w,
(SELECT SUM(weight) FROM test t1 WHERE t1.bill_id = t.bill_id AND t1.typecode = "S" AND t1.metal_type = "SILVER") as silver_s_w,
(SELECT SUM(weight) FROM test t1 WHERE t1.bill_id = t.bill_id AND t1.typecode = "R" AND t1.metal_type = "SILVER") as silver_r_w
FROM `test` t 
WHERE 1 
GROUP BY bill_id
```

In YII2 must be like:

```
$bill_details = BillDetails::find()
->select([
    'bill_id',
    '(SELECT SUM(weight) FROM bill_details bt2 WHERE bt2.bill_id = bill_details.bill_id AND bt2.typecode = "S" AND bt2.metal_type = "GOLD") as gold_s_w',
    '(SELECT SUM(weight) FROM bill_details bt2 WHERE bt2.bill_id = bill_details.bill_id AND bt2.typecode = "R" AND bt2.metal_type = "GOLD") as gold_r_w',
    '(SELECT SUM(weight) FROM bill_details bt2 WHERE bt2.bill_id = bill_details.bill_id AND bt2.typecode = "S" AND bt2.metal_type = "SILVER") as silver_s_w',
    '(SELECT SUM(weight) FROM bill_details bt2 WHERE bt2.bill_id = bill_details.bill_id AND bt2.typecode = "R" AND bt2.metal_type = "SILVER") as silver_r_w',
])
->groupby('bill_id')
->asArray()
->all();
```

Comment: it results sum(weight), actually i need 3 different columns that is why i selected weight AS gold_s_w,gold_r_w and so on ,thanks

Comment: Actually everywhere you `SELECT SUM(weight)`, if you run this query you'll see that you have information that you need (combination from `typecode`, `metal_type`, `sum_of_weight` for every `bill_id`), just you have to loop array and check if `metal_type` is GOLD, SILVER and etc. Also if you add new `metal_type` or `typecode` then query will return all possible variations that you store in you database without need to rewrite your query with `addSelect` :)

Comment: @code-droid I updated my answer.Check it :)

Answer (score 0):

Better solution for this type of scenarios

```
$bill_details->addSelect("sum(IF(billdetails.typecode = 'S' and billdetails.metaltype ='gold',billdetails.weight,0)) AS gold_s_w");
$bill_details->addSelect("sum(IF(billdetails.typecode = 'R' and billdetails.metaltype ='gold',billdetails.weight,0)) AS gold_r_w");
$bill_details->addSelect("sum(IF(billdetails.typecode = 'S' and billdetails.metaltype ='silver',billdetails.weight,0)) AS silver_s_w");
$bill_details->addSelect("sum(IF(billdetails.typecode = 'R' and billdetails.metaltype ='silver',billdetails.weight,0)) AS silver_s_r");
```

Comment: what is 0 refers inside if conditions

Comment: if condition is true take billdetails.weight and if condition is false take 0